# Why mysqld costing so much memory?

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner of Linux. The memory of the server computer is 2GB.

I just installed a MySQL-server:latest version in docker and run it in a container.

Now the MySQL has not any database tables, just a brand new MySQL.

Whereas, the CentOS8 hangs frequently after I installed it.

I checked the memory cost like this:

```
[root@test ~]# ps -aux | sort -k4nr | head -10
mysql    19410  1.1 20.9 1854552 391940 ?      Ssl  20:34   0:01 mysqld
root      1452  0.4 12.0 3151680 225168 ?      Sl   18:49   0:30 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
root     19101  3.6  7.9 1276148 149300 pts/1  SLl+ 20:33   0:07 /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
root      2088  0.1  2.4 1143892 45092 ?       Ssl  18:50   0:06 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root      1351  0.0  2.0 569096 37964 tty1     S<l  18:49   0:05 /usr/libexec/Xorg :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /root/.serverauth.1328
root      1800  0.0  1.9 1401944 37036 ?       Sl   18:49   0:01 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
root      2464  0.0  1.5 12032812 28968 ?      SLsl 18:51   0:06 dotnet test.dll
root      1922  0.0  1.4 368984 27032 ?        S    18:49   0:00 /usr/libexec/platform-python /usr/libexec/rhsmd
root      2087  0.3  1.4 1133376 26504 ?       Ssl  18:50   0:20 /usr/bin/containerd
root      2740  0.2  1.2 204224 22576 ?        Ss   18:59   0:16 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_kcm --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
```

As you see, `mysqld` costs the most.

After I kill the `mysqld`, all run well. The system will not hang anymore while I can not access the database also.

I never meet this before even running the MySQL in windows sever 2016 on the same computer.

How can I solve this? Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the configuration file.  Lower this setting:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 300M
```

It is probably bigger than that, hence using up a bunch of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

2GB memory isn't that much, particularly for a server. (My 2+ year old mobile phone has 2x more RAM than your server)

2 CPU cores & 2GB is the bare minimum needed to be in a supported configuration for MySQL. Database systems are memory intensive, since they are designed to handle large amounts of data. RDBMSs want to hold data in memory to avoid performing physical IO operations.

It's safe to assume that this 2GB minimum accounts for the OS & MySQL, and *nothing else* to be running on the server.

I notice from the output of your `ps` command that you're also running MySQL Workbench, Docker, Python, and some other bits. Alone, none of these are resource intensive, but they all have their own memory & CPU needs, which are competing for a very small amount of memory.

Ultimately, you just need more horsepower, particularly if performance is important. You could try moving everything except MySQL to a different server, and exploring distros that are as minimalist as possible, but success on that route is not guaranteed.  Simply adding more memory (and possibly vCPUs... Given the small memory footprint, I assume a very low number of CPUs) is a "sure thing"

Comment: I have not so much money that only can rent an inexpensive server computer online. I only use a docker&.net core&mysql on this computer. I installed python only for the runtime of workbench.

Comment: I am using a 1GB&1 CPU CORE server computer before. I installed a windows server 2012R system on it, running a .net core&mysql only. However, it all runs well. Then I am about to modify the whole project to this computer which is better .Now I feel so strange that it seems the performance of MySQL is running worse in linux than windows.